# Finding probabilities from a density function

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, density-function

I have a region $W$ with vertexes in $(0,0,0), (2,0,0), (0,3,0),(0,0,1)$ (a pyramid).

I have the random vector $(X,Y,Z)$ with the density $c$ if $(x,y,z) \in W$ and $0$ otherwise.

To find $c$ I do $$V = \int_{x=0}^{x=2} \int_{y=0}^{3-3x/2} \int_{z=0}^{z=1-x/2-y/3} dz \, dy \, dx,$$ and I get that $c=1$

What's $P\{\frac{1}{3} \leq Z \leq \frac{2}{3}\ | X= \frac{1}{4}, Y= \frac{1}$ ?

Comment: If the density is really $1$ over the region $W$, then the indicated probability is just the volume of the horizontal slice of $W$ between the planes $z=\frac13$ and $z=\frac23$

Comment: How can I calculate that?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to change the order of integration so you are doing something like $\int_{z=1/3}^{z=2/3}\int_{y=\cdots}^{y=\cdots}\int_{x=\cdots}^{x=\cdots}dx \; dy \; dz$. The main point is to have integration with respect to $z$ on the outside so you can easily control the limits of integration.

Comment: So i should find new regions of integration for $y$ and $x$ taking in consideration that i have $\frac{1}{3} \leq z \leq \frac{2}{3}$

Comment: That's right. It is an arbitrary choice to look at the limits of $x$ first and put those limits on the outermost integral, so you can just follow the same logic as when you did that, but look at $z$ first.